# Custom grid.phtml For Just CMS > Pages

Tags: magento

I'm making my first extension trying to learn Magento. I'm kind of stuck at a part, because I'm wanting to customize the `\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\grid.phtml` file, BUT more than just CMS > Pages uses that file. Is there anyway to break it out so that the CMS > Pages section points to a different `grid.phtml` file? Surely there is a way I just can't seem to figure it out at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have your own extension, you can change block template via your layout update file. If you don't have one, create it (app/design/adminhtml/default/default/your_extension.xml) and add the following lines into *adminhtml* section of your extension's config.xml:

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <your_extension>
            <file>your_extension.xml</file>
        </your_extension>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

And your layout update file (in our case it is your_extension.xml) should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_cms_page_index>
        <reference name="cms_page.grid">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>widget/grid2.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_cms_page_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: I ended up just rewriting cms_page_grid in my config.xml file and then defining my own theme. Then within my custom Grid.php I set `$this->setTemplate('widget/grid2.phtml');` then had it extend Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Grid ... this way if I write any more extensions that require my own custom theming I can keep all my custom template files separate from magentos default files.

Comment: I don't quite understand your reasoning, but of course suit yourself. Rewrite is a valid way, but I think that in this case it is an overkill which may cause some problems in future. For example, if you will need to install some 3rd party extension, which also rewrites this grid. I've seen too many "how do I solve extension conflict" questions on this website.

Comment: Well like I said in my post "I'm making my first extension trying to learn Magento"... maybe in your solution you should have mentioned how this helps solve extension conflicts... now that you say that I am going to explore and most likely end up using your solution

Comment: It really depends on your situation. If you need to change only template, layout update is an optimal way. But if you think that in future you will need to change logic of this grid (e.g. _prepareCollection method), then you will have to either rewrite this block, or search for some other way.

Comment: Ok i've copy and pasted exactly what you have above within my config.xml `<blocks><adminhtml><layout><updates>` and then created the your_extension.xml within app/design/adminhtml/default/default but im not seeing any changes... thoughts?

Comment: well i just want to do it the right way... I have clients that will end up using this extension and im sure they'll have other extensions too :)

Comment: The full path should be `<config><adminhtml><layout><updates>` - without blocks node

Comment: grrr still not working... <config><adminhtml><layout><updates> i also tried changing your_extension to the name of my extension keeping everything lowercase... inside my custom etc file I have an adminhtml.xml file besides a config.xml file could that be causing a problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30419/discussion-between-alexei-yerofeyev-and-banning)

Comment: Thanks to Alexeis help the issue was the your_extension.xml file was in the wrong place app > design > adminhtml > default > default > layout > your_extension.xml

Answer (score 1):

Within `__construct` in the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Grid` I can put this code

```
$this->setTemplate('widget/grid2.phtml');
```

and define whatever template I want. Awesome. Now it is just a matter of making it all upgrade friendly and including it all into my extension in the `config.xml` file.